# blur header element in HTML through angularJS directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

I have a button. When that button is clicked, I want to blur everything within my HTML `header` element.

I want to accomplish this through directives, and it looks like this

```
.directive('setUpBlur', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                classElement: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.find(scope.classElement).css("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");
            }
       };

    });
```

The button within the header looks like this:

```
<button set-up-blur class-element="header">Generate</button>
```

But nothing happens:

If I write the following CSS, it works:

```
header {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you trying to find by css class? Does the element.find() return anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.directive('setUpBlur', function($rootElement){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                classElement: '@'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                $rootElement.find(scope.classElement).css("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");
            }
       };

    });
```

Comment: that worked - thanks :) But why `$rootElement`. Why not `element`?

Comment: element is referring to the button element, and 'find' finds child elements. I assume your scope.classElement is not child of Button.

Comment: Also, If I only want to do this after the button is pressed? I tried to make a function in the controller and ng-click in the html, but dom-related stuff should be in directives? Problem is this directive is called straight away